# Firebase - Installed Build Tools revision is corrupted

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to add Firebase into my android application. I'm getting this error

[Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYoKP.png)

In build.gradle there's an error

`Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.`

I uninstalled the current Android SDK Build-Tool 31 and installed it again from SDK Manager but I'm still getting the same error.

What should I do to resolve this issue?